# Records Created by Apex Class not Created During Test

Tags: apex, unit-test

I'm struggling to perform some assertions on a class, coverage is fine.

So I have a method similar to the following in an Apex Class:

```
public PageReference createContact() {
    Contact c = new Contact(
        FirstName = 'Foo',
        LastName = 'Bar',
        AccountId = a.Id
    );

    INSERT c;
    return null;
}
```

And can call this method in a test class similar to below:

```
@isTest static void test_createContact() {
    MyController pagecon = new Mycontroller();
    pagecon.createContact();
}
```

This works to the extent that it covers the method, but what I want to do is assert that a record is created.

I've tried querying the Contact object just by counting how many records exist. In theory, once I've ran that particular method, one record should surely exist? However. When I assert this, the query returns 0 instead of 1.

```
Integer checkExists = [SELECT Count() FROM Contact]; // Should return 1

System.assertEquals(1, checkExists); // Expect: 1, Actual: 0
```

The whole thing looks like this:

```
@isTest static void test_createContact() {
    MyController pagecon = new Mycontroller();
    pagecon.createContact();

    Integer checkExists = [SELECT Count() FROM Contact]; // Should return 1

    System.assertEquals(1, checkExists); // Expect: 1, Actual: 0
}
```

How would I check that a record has been created? If I create a record in `@testSetup` I can query that, but if that record created is a result of a method in an Apex class, it doesn't exist in that test instance. Am I missing something here?

**Edit**
I accidentally missed off the `INSERT` from the `createContact` method! That is actually in there, but the problem remains the same! :)

Comment: Do you not have any error handling around your `insert` call? Perhaps something is being suppressed in a `catch` block.

Comment: @AdrianLarson I do, that particular method is covering the `try` but not covering the `catch` which is what I'd expect to see. So I know it's executing the `INSERT`. I tried just removing the `try{}catch(){}` altogether and it still won't assert as expected.

Comment: Try adding `system.assertEquals(1, [SELECT count() FROM Contact])` right after your `DML` call and then `system.assert(false)` after that. One of those two should fail according to your test.

Comment: @AdrianLarson `System.assertEquals(1, [SELECT Count() FROM Contact]);` failed, expecting 1, actually getting 0. What's strange is if, in the Sandbox, I enter exactly the same information as programmed in the test class, it creates the record. So I know it's all working. Just this damn assertion!

Comment: Do you somehow have create but not read permission?

Comment: @AdrianLarson I know I do, but I decided to do a `System.runAs()` with the profile being System Administrator, same problem!

Comment: I just ran the code I the test passed for me.

Comment: Do you have any triggers that delete `Contact` records you may be tripping?

Comment: @AdrianLarson Checked it. Nothing unfortunately!

Comment: Can you post the whole log of the test at pastebin and share it.

Comment: @manjit_singh Sure! Although I'm not entirely sure how I get a test log?

Comment: testmethod doesn't mock Account, so inserted Contact a.id = null; is this your issue?

Comment: This test is passing for me as well in a new DE. That said, I'm wondering about the AccountId from your controller. Where is the variable 'a' being instantiated?

Comment: @crop1645 The account is instantiated. So sadly it's not that. Again, when run "live", it does what's expected. For some reason though, doing the exact same thing programatically it seems to either not actually create/commit the record, or it's being deleted. I'm starting to wonder whether this isn't a bug and it's something outside of the "app" itself.

Comment: Poet - since others can't reproduce this and you say your real method is 'like' the one you posted (presumably you stripped out bits you felt were not relevant - and we thank you for that) - can you create a new method in the controller that builds up from what you posted, then add in other bits from your real code until you get the assertion error?

Comment: @poet - I think you're going to need a debug log. Run the test from the Dev Console, and then hop over to the Log tab and you should find the log from that test run.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally got to the bottom of it,

As advised by @manjit_singh and @ChristianCarter to look at the log I saw an error where the problem was to do with a custom setting in a Trigger.

Effectively the Trigger has a line similar to the following:

```
if (Custom_Setting__c.getInstance('ABC123').Value__c=='True') {
```

I'm not sure entirely what this does (haven't looked a whole lot at Custom Settings), but it must be in some way connected to the Contact object and, by default, set to `false`.

So, in the `@testSetup` I just needed to add the following:

```
Custom_Setting__c customSetting4 = new Custom_Setting__c(
  Name = 'ABC123',
  Value__c = 'True'
);
```

Either way, all of this was found as a result of looking at the Test Logs.

Really appreciate you guys responding and firing some ideas (and eventually guiding me to the root of the problem!) it's massively appreciated. Although this would've deployed fine with respect to coverage and just omitting the assertion, I did want to get to the bottom of it.

I'm just suprised Salesforce wasn't a bit more vocal about the fact the Trigger was failing as a consequence of the Custom Setting!

Comment: Custom Settings are just another sobject(s) and if not mocked in testclasses, will lead to issues like this. I have a common testsetup method that mocks all my custom settings and it is the first line in every testmethod. Also, VF code should have try-catch with apex.pageMessages on caught exceptions and you should assert in testmethod whether any errors were caught. This avoids having to look in logs (at least initially)

Comment: @crop1645 There is an undocumented limit to the number of `DML Rows` across all tests. I would be careful inserting data I don't know I need (assuming you really set up *all* custom setting data). I'll see if I can find a reference for that claim.

Comment: @crop1645 I understand. Thank you! I've had encounters with Custom Settings before with respect to Apex, just never needed to use them myself from a declarative sense hence why my knowledge is a bit low on it. I did have stuff in a `try` & `catch` but I only delivered stuff to the Page itself, rather than using `System.debug()`. Lesson learned.

Comment: @AdrianLarson - the # of custom settings in my orgs that need to be mocked is on the order of 10 rows so your concern (a good one) didn't apply - the settings I mock are the ones holding config parameters (like trigger kill switches, appleman async pattern kill switch, and email address to send notifications to sysad; I certainly wouldn't mock hundreds/thousands of rows in custom settings if they were modeling some postalcode to state lookup table

Comment: Kind of disturbing the CS uses 'True' instead of a checkbox...

Comment: @AdrianLarson Tell me about it. There's also a lot of these that use Strings instead of Booleans and they're everywhere.